# compute all pairwise differences within a vector in R

Tags: r

There are several posts on computing pairwise differences among vectors, but I cannot find how to compute all differences within a vector.

Say I have a vector, v.

```
v<-c(1:4)
```

I would like to generate a second vector that is the absolute value of all pairwise differences within the vector. Similar to:

```
abs(1-2) = 1
abs(1-3) = 2
abs(1-4) = 3
abs(2-3) = 1
abs(2-4) = 2
abs(3-4) = 1
```

The output would be a vector of 6 values, which are the result of my 6 comparisons:

```
output<- c(1,2,3,1,2,1)
```

Is there a function in R that can do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
as.numeric(dist(v))
```

seems to work; it treats `v` as a column matrix and computes the Euclidean distance between rows, which in this case is `sqrt((x-y)^2)=abs(x-y)`

If we're golfing, then I'll offer `c(dist(v))`, which is equivalent and which I'm guessing will be unbeatable.

@AndreyShabalin makes the good point that using `method="manhattan"` will probably be slightly more efficient since it avoids the squaring/square-rooting stuff.

Comment: To avoid square roots you could use another metric: `as.vector(dist(v, method = "manhattan"))`.

Comment: Hmm, something was borked. Somehow the solution was off by a factor of 100.

Answer (score 16):

Let's play golf

```
abs(apply(combn(1:4,2), 2, diff))
```

@Ben, yours is a killer!

```
> system.time(apply(combn(1:1000,2), 2, diff))
   user  system elapsed 
   6.65    0.00    6.67 
> system.time(c(dist(1:1000)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.01 
> system.time({
+ v <- 1:1000
+ z = outer(v,v,'-');
+ z[lower.tri(z)];
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.03    0.00    0.03
```

Who knew that elegant (read understandable/flexible) code can be so slow.

Comment: can you beat `c(dist(v))` (10 characters) ?  (yours could be slightly shorter if you substitute `v` for `1:4`)

Comment: Huh! I thought @BenBolker would win the tournament. I'd assume my example introduces 3 commonly used functions in one line as a bonus.

Comment: They both work well. I accepted this answer because I could understand what was going on more clearly. Furthermore, I can easily modify this code to do other pairwise operation (i.e. compute pairwise sums for the same vector). I can't do that with the dist() function.

Comment: it will be interesting to see how the benchmarking goes, if @Vlo actually does it.  This solution does fewer than half as many operations, but it does them less efficiently.

Comment: we could all switch to Julia :-)

Comment: +1 `combn` has a `FUN` argument, so you could just do: `combn(v,2,FUN=diff)`

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Wow! Never cared to check for this function details. It takes 2/3 of time of that with apply.

Answer (score 15):

A possible solution is:

```
z = outer(v,v,'-'); 
z[lower.tri(z)];

[1] 1 2 3 1 2 1
```

Comment: semicolons are unnecessary, and mildly inefficient (full matrix is computed) but otherwise very nice.

Comment: I had ``sapply(v, "-", v) `` before looking here. ``outer`` is nice!