# R function to calculate all pairs of index a certain distance apart

Tags: r

Given a data frame with a numerical column, what's a quick way to determine a matrix of index pairs such that the absolute distance of the associated numerical numbers equal something fixed?

Example:

```
index x
  1   5
  2   7
  3   8
  4   9
  5   9.5
```

and the output should be

```
index1 index2
   2     3
   3     4
```

if the fixed distance is 1, and

```
index1 index2
  1      2
```

if the fixed distance is 2.

Comment: If the fixed distance is 2 should there also be a `index = 2/index = 4` pair?

Comment: Are the values of x sorted as in your example?

Answer (score 1):

One option is `sqldf` where you merge `df` onto itself based on the differences in the `x` column:

```
library(sqldf)
res <- sqldf("SELECT l.`index` as index1, r.`index` as index2
              FROM df        as l
              INNER JOIN df  as r
              ON r.x - l.x = 1")

res
#  index1 index2
#1      2      3
#2      3      4
```

---

Another option is one like in this post [compute all pairwise differences within a vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314878/compute-all-pairwise-differences-within-a-vector-in-r) but it requires a little more work to get it in the format you want:

```
dist_mat  <- as.matrix(dist(df[,2]))
dist_mat2 <- dist_mat*lower.tri(dist_mat)
res <- data.frame(index1=rep(row.names(dist_mat2),ncol(dist_mat2)),
                 index2=rep(colnames(dist_mat2),each=nrow(dist_mat2)),
                 x=c(dist_mat2))

res[res$x== 1, c("index1","index2")]
```

Note this could be problematic if you wanted the values where the difference is `0` since I have to multiply by the `lower.tri` matrix so you don't have repeated combinations (e.g. `2/3` and `3/2`). However, the benefit of this is you only need to do it once. So if you wanted where the difference is `2` you could change the last line to `res$x==2`.