# Compute all pairwise differences of elements in a vector

Tags: r

my question is very closely related to a previous post: [compute all pairwise differences within a vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314878/compute-all-pairwise-differences-within-a-vector-in-r)

But I'm interested in the difference of these elements not the absolute difference, which makes all suggested solutions infeasible.

I know how to obtain a result with this command:

```
n <- 4
x <- c(1:4)
combn(x,2, FUN=diff)
```

But this is too slow for my application where n=500/1000/... .
What would be the most efficient way to do this in R

Comment: Where have you used `n` in your code?

Comment: @MKR OP probably wanted to write `x <- c(1:n)`

Comment: I think this task will be solved by the `outer`-method as proposed by Andrey Shabalin in the related post.

Comment: Take a look at the `dist` function.  This is O^2 calculation so as n increase the calculation time with increase quickly.

Comment: Also, what is you final purpose ? If it is for strings, for exemple, there is lot already said .. e.g. [efficent string similarity grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058104/efficient-string-similarity-grouping/48096986#48096986)

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with `outer`

```
x <- c(1:4)
outer(x,x, `-`)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0   -1   -2   -3
[2,]    1    0   -1   -2
[3,]    2    1    0   -1
[4,]    3    2    1    0
```

Comment: Your right, this is also much faster then combn(). 
I was aware of outer() in the related post, but I guess I overlooked sth when applying it.
Thanks!