# Differences between all possible pairs of rows for all columns within each level of factor

Tags: r, dplyr, combn

I want to build **all possible pairs of rows** in a dataframe **within each level** of a categorical variable `name` and then make the differences of these rows  within each level of `name` for all non-factor variables: row 1 - row 2, row 1 - row 3, …

```r
set.seed(9)
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:10,
  name = as.factor(rep(LETTERS, each = 4)[1:10]),
  X1 = sample(1001, 10),
  X2 = sample(1001, 10),
  bool = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace = TRUE),
  fruit = as.factor(sample(c("Apple", "Orange", "Kiwi"), 10, replace = TRUE))
)
```

This is what the sample looks like:

```
   ID name  X1  X2  bool  fruit
1   1    A 222 118 FALSE  Apple
2   2    A  25   9  TRUE   Kiwi
3   3    A 207 883  TRUE Orange
4   4    A 216 301  TRUE   Kiwi
5   5    B 443 492 FALSE  Apple
6   6    B 134 499 FALSE   Kiwi
7   7    B 389 401  TRUE   Kiwi
8   8    B 368 972  TRUE   Kiwi
9   9    C 665 356 FALSE  Apple
10 10    C 985 488 FALSE   Kiwi
```

I want to get a dataframe of 13 rows which looks like :

```
   ID  name  X1   X2  bool  fruit
1  1-2    A 197  109    -1  Apple
2  1-3    A  15 -765    -1   Kiwi
…
```

Note that the factor `fruit` should be unchanged. But it is a bonus, I want above all the `X1` and `X2` to be changed and the factor `name` to be kept.

I know I may use `combn` function but I do not see how to do it. I would prefer a solution with the `dplyr` package and the `group_by` function.

I've managed to create all differences for consecutives rows with `dplyr` using

```
varnotfac <- names(df)[!sapply(df, is.factor )] # remove factorial variable
# but not logical variable

library(dplyr)
diff <- df%>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate_at(varnotfac, funs(. - lead(.))) %>% #      
  na.omit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sample looks different...

> ```
>    ID name  X1  X2  bool
> 1   1    A 222 118 FALSE
> 2   2    A  25   9  TRUE
> 3   3    A 207 883  TRUE
> 4   4    A 216 301  TRUE
> 5   5    B 443 492 FALSE
> 6   6    B 134 499 FALSE
> 7   7    B 389 401  TRUE
> 8   8    B 368 972  TRUE
> 9   9    C 665 356 FALSE
> 10 10    C 985 488 FALSE
> ```

Using this, and looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314878/compute-all-pairwise-differences-within-a-vector-in-r#24314954), we can do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, ~as.data.frame(map(.x, ~as.numeric(dist(.)))))) %>% 
  unnest()
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 13 x 5
>    name     ID    X1    X2  bool
>    <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
>  1 A         1   197   109     1
>  2 A         2    15   765     1
>  3 A         3     6   183     1
>  4 A         1   182   874     0
>  5 A         2   191   292     0
>  6 A         1     9   582     0
>  7 B         1   309     7     0
>  8 B         2    54    91     1
>  9 B         3    75   480     1
> 10 B         1   255    98     1
> 11 B         2   234   473     1
> 12 B         1    21   571     0
> 13 C         1   320   132     0
> ```

This is unsigned though. Alternatively:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, ~as.data.frame(map(.x, ~combn(., 2, diff))))) %>% 
  unnest()
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 13 x 5
>    name     ID    X1    X2  bool
>    <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int>
>  1 A         1  -197  -109     1
>  2 A         2   -15   765     1
>  3 A         3    -6   183     1
>  4 A         1   182   874     0
>  5 A         2   191   292     0
>  6 A         1     9  -582     0
>  7 B         1  -309     7     0
>  8 B         2   -54   -91     1
>  9 B         3   -75   480     1
> 10 B         1   255   -98     1
> 11 B         2   234   473     1
> 12 B         1   -21   571     0
> 13 C         1   320   132     0
> ```

Comment: Also for the data.frame that I have?

Comment: You're right. My fault. I edited my printed dataframe. I should look at the `nest`and `map` function. Thanks

Comment: I've got other factors in the dataframe. The last code send the message

`Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: malformed factor.`

Comment: Should I use  `mutate_at(varnotfac, data = map(data, ~as.data.frame(map(.x, ~  -combn(., 2, diff)))))` instead ?

Comment: I don't know. I solved the question as it is given. I guess you could just `filter_if` first.

Comment: Please consider the new data.frame with the extra column

Comment: I am new to `dplyr`. I cannot make it work with `filter_at(varnotfac, any_vars())`.    
  `Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types.`  

Even a solution without `dplyr` will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find out how to keep all variables using `filter_if` / `filter_at` so I used `select_at`. So from [@Axeman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834793/8806649)

```
set.seed(9)
varnotfac <- names(df)[!sapply(df, is.factor )] # names of non-factorial variables

 diff1<- df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  select_at(vars(varnotfac)) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(data = purrr::map(data, ~as.data.frame(map(.x, ~combn(., 2, base::diff))))) %>% 
  unnest()
```

Or with the `outer` function, it's way faster than `combn`

```
set.seed(9)
varnotfac <- names(df)[!sapply(df, is.factor )] # names of non-factorial variables

allpairs <- function(v){
  y <- outer(v,v,'-')
  z <- y[lower.tri(y)]
  return(z)
}

diff2<- df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  select_at(vars(varnotfac)) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(data = purrr::map(data, ~as.data.frame(map(.x, ~allpairs(.))))) %>% 
  unnest()
)
```

One can check that the data.frame obtained are the same with

```
all.equal(diff1,diff2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have said `select_if`, my fault. I guess `select_if(is.numeric)` would work?

Comment: The drawback of `select_if` and `select_at` is that it removes the variable `fruit`. I still Don't know how to keep this column

Comment: It's unclear what that column would say, what is Apple minus Kiwi?

Comment: Yes, I should dummy the variables first